Solving a system of coupled differential equations using eigenvalues and eigenvectors
I have the following the system of coupled differential equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2g & -\Delta \\ \Delta & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y \\ z\end{bmatrix}.
$$
With the boundary condition $[0,  1]^{\top}$. I'm trying to solve this for $z$ by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the system matrix. According to the tutorial which only shows the solution gives the result as $z(t) = cos(2\pi t)e^{-gt}$ however, I cannot get anything close to this. How could I tackle this?

Either the given equations are incorrect or the solution is wrong (it's definitely unclear where $2\pi$ in the $\cos$ comes from). $y$ solves a damped harmonic oscillator that looks like $e^{-t} \sin (kt)$ (up to constants) after applying the boundary conditions, so $z$ will be a sum of a $\sin$ and $\cos$ term multiplied by an exponential.

(1) What do you mean by "with the boundary condition $[0,  1]^{\top}$"? $(y(0), z(0))=(0, 1)$? (2) Is there a relation between $g$ and $\Delta$?

@Moo
https://nbviewer.org/urls/qutip.org/qutip-tutorials/tutorials-v5/time-evolution/003_qubit-dynamics.ipynb
This is where problem comes from the differential equations are not explicitly written here but I derived them using d/dt z = Tr[z*d/dt rho] where rho is the Lindbladian.

@kipf When I coded this problem and solved it using np.linalg() the solution matched the analytical result they presented up to 10^-2.

@Gonçalo, (1) Yes that's what I mean by boundary condition. (2)There is no relationship between g and Delta.

In the Jupyter notebook it seems that $\Delta=2\pi$. Am I right?

@Gonçalo yes but im not sure if for the analytical soltuion they mean cos(Delta*t)e^-gt because g takes the value 0.25 and they choose not to write that explicitly in the exponent. (Also sorry for the delayed responses).

The eigenvalues of your matrix are
$\lambda=-g\pm\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}$. Hence, the system of ODEs in the new set of coordinates $(\{y,z\}\to\{\tilde y,\tilde z\})$ becomes
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde y\\
\tilde z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\!\!\!\! & 0\\
0 & -g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde y\\
\tilde z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Both differential equations are of the form
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d \varphi(t)}{\mathrm d t}=k\varphi$$
with solution
$$\varphi(t)=Ce^{kt}$$
Therefore,
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\tilde y=C_1\exp\left[\left(-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\right)\,\!\!t\right]\\
&\tilde z=C_2\exp\left[\left(-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\right)\,\!\!t\right]
\end{aligned}\right.$$
What's left now is finding the eigenvectors in order to convert back to our original set of coordinates, $\{y,z\}$ and afterwards apply initial conditions. Let's treat each particular case:

$\lambda=-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}:$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & -\Delta\\
\Delta & +g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{11}\\
v_{21}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\implies \small(v_{11},v_{21})=\left(\dfrac{-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta},1\right)
$$
$\lambda=-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}:$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! & -\Delta\\
\Delta & +g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{12}\\
v_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\implies \small(v_{12},v_{22})=\left(\dfrac{-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta},1\right)
$$
This means, then, that both sets of coordinates are related through the change of basis matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta} & \dfrac{-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta}\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
In this way,
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&y=\dfrac{-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta}\tilde y+\dfrac{-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta}\tilde z\\
&z=\tilde y+\tilde z
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Now we can proceed by imposing the initial conditions
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&0=\dfrac{-g+\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta}C_1+\dfrac{-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{\Delta}C_2\\
&1=C_1+C_2
\end{aligned}\right.$$
obtaining
$$C_1=\dfrac{-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{2\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}};\ C_2=\dfrac{g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}{2\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}$$
Now and at last we'll focus only on $z(t)$ as to check whether the solution I got coincides with your supposed one, $z(t)=\cos(2\pi t)e^{-gt}$. We have
$$\small z(t)=\dfrac{e^{-gt}}{2\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}}\left\{\left(-g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\right)\exp\left[\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}t\right]+\left(g-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}\right)\exp\left[-\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}t\right]\right\}$$
Notice how $g<\Delta$ according to the link you cited and  thus $\sqrt{g^2-\Delta^2}=i\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}$. Thusly,
$$\begin{aligned}
\small z(t)&\small=\dfrac{e^{-gt}}{2i\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}}\left\{\left(-g-i\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}\right)\exp\left[i\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}t\right]+\left(g-i\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}\right)\exp\left[-i\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}t\right]\right\}\\
&\small=-\dfrac{e^{-gt}}{\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}}\left\{\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}\cos\left(\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}t\right)+g\sin\left(\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}t\right)\right\}\\
&\small=-\dfrac{\Delta^2 e^{-gt}}{\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}}\sin\left[\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}t+\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{\Delta^2-g^2}}{g}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}$$
I'm not sure how they got that solution, it might be a particular solution, then?


Thanks! I don't understand the last step, if g=0 then surely the argument of the expoential =0 and the fucntion would be periodic only. However, clearly from the plot on the link it has a decay also.

I just noticed, thanks for pointing that out.
